# tar: Refusing to read archive contents from terminal (missing -f option?)

Tags: tar, error-handling

I tried to unzip using tar -xvgf filename and it shows error like : tar: Refusing to read archive contents from terminal (missing -f option?)

Comment: Error like or is this the actual error? Does this help https://www.tecmint.com/18-tar-command-examples-in-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Why the `g` in `xvgf`?

Based on [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_22.html):

```
`-g snapshot-file'
During a `--create' operation, specifies that the archive that tar creates is a
new GNU-format incremental backup, using snapshot-file to determine which files
to backup. With other operations, informs tar that the archive is in incremental
format.
```

It's not needed. Instead, do:

```
tar -xvf <filename>
```

Comment: Oops!.It should be 'z' . So that was my mistake